# IP address ranges for EC2

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there any public info on what public IP address ranges Amazon EC2 uses? I would like to be able to lookup an IP and know whether or not it's an EC2 machine. I know that the DNS name given to EC2 machines gives a hint that it's an EC2 account, but I really prefer to just have an IP lookup available.

Tx, Simon @ http://LabSlice.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon maintains the list of EC2 IP Ranges here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

Comment: The post seems to come and go.  Perhaps people should go to the top level EC2 forum URL (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30) and look for the most recent sticky posting for the latest IP ranges info.

Comment: The list is formally published by AWS in a JSON file. [See Bernado Matinez' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115143/1318694)

Answer (score 8):

You can find information on the public IP ranges used by AWS here:
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

See the documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

Comment: The process to monitor for IP changes for a particular service can be automated as explained in the post https://medium.com/@shashidharyamsani/smart-notifications-for-aws-ip-range-changes-6e68b48b3505

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different sources, but none of them are amazing.

BigJoe mentions https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701. (If this is broken, try looking for the top sticky in the [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30).)

There's also http://ec2-reachability.amazonaws.com/, which is a less concise list since it includes several narrower ranges for testing IP routing.

For a processed version of those two in a more machine readable format, you might try https://github.com/ab/ec2-ip.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar so I built this tool. It will let you look up the IP ranges by service and region. Then you could check if the IP falls within those ranges. https://shotstack.io/tools/aws-ip-search-tool/

Answer (score -1):

Here's an other link:
http://www.uncompiled.com/2010/04/current-amazon-ec2-public-ip-ranges/

```
 US East (Northern Virginia):
 216.182.224.0/20 (216.182.224.0 – 216.182.239.255)
 72.44.32.0/19 (72.44.32.0 – 72.44.63.255)
 67.202.0.0/18 (67.202.0.0 – 67.202.63.255)
 75.101.128.0/17 (75.101.128.0 – 75.101.255.255)
 174.129.0.0/16 (174.129.0.0 – 174.129.255.255)
 204.236.192.0/18 (204.236.192.0 – 204.236.255.255)
 184.73.0.0/16 (184.73.0.0 – 184.73.255.255)
 184.72.128.0/17 (184.72.128.0 – 184.72.255.255)

 US West (Northern California):
 204.236.128.0/18 (216.236.128.0 – 216.236.191.255)
 184.72.0.0/18 (184.72.0.0 – 184.72.63.255)


  EU (Ireland):
  79.125.0.0/17 (79.125.0.0 – 79.125.127.255)

  Asia Pacific (Singapore)
  175.41.128.0/18 (175.41.128.0 – 175.41.191.255)
```